# I can't move letters from string to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to move all pair of letters in this way but i have an **error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Arg_ParamName_Name'**  I dont understand what problem is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "helloworld";

            string[] str2 = new string[5];

            str2[0] = str.Substring(0, 2);
            str2[1] = str.Substring(2, 4);
            str2[2] = str.Substring(4, 6);
            str2[3] = str.Substring(6, 8);
            str2[4] = str.Substring(8, 10);

            Console.WriteLine(str2);
            
            
        }

            
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32) the second parameter is the length of the substring. Make all your second parameters 2 and it should be fine. The error message is really an out of bounds error

Comment: The [`String.Substring()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)) you are using takes **start index** and **length of substring** as parameters. If you replace the second input parameter in all your method calls to 2, it would work as expected.

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) ? (22 minutes to read, way more time delivered)

Comment: FYI you could use ranges instead for this to work like `str2[2] = str[4..6]`

Answer (score 0):

by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0

```
public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);
```

note startIndex=6 length=8 is out side of str(str.Length = 10)

Answer (score 0):

The Substring method of C#, takes the parameters as starting index of the substring in string, i.e. the position of your substring in the string and the length of this substring, i.e. how many characters should be there in the substring (including the starting index's character).
Thus at line `str[3] = str.Substring(6, 8)` it tries to go to index 6 and then tries to add 8 characters from there... which it can't since there are only 4 (i.e. the indexes 6, 7, 8, 9).
Thus it raises the exception.